# What is going on with undeletion lately?

Tags: discussion, deleted-questions, undeletion

Some questions have been undeleted that... frankly, shouldn't have been. 10k users can see the whole list [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/tools?tab=delete&daterange=last7days), but here they are for the pleasure of everyone else:

- https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1027676/how-to-find-the-value-of-this-limit-lim-limits-n-to-infty-fracx-cdot-n21
- https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1029225/evaluating-int-2x-ex2-dx
- https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/974943/solve-9x230x25-0-using-quadratic-formula
- https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1014963/find-a-3-times1-non-zero-real-matrix-b-such-that-ab-0
- https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1013742/if-a-b-1-then-ab-a-b-namb-has-no-natural-solution

I especially encourage you to look at the first revisions of these questions. I think they speak for themselves. Then *some people* edit these questions to add some basic layer of words around the math symbols, so that they don't look like utter garbage. But they're still zero-effort PSQ (that WolframAlpha can answer in most cases). Can someone explain what's going on?

Comment: I looked at the 1st of the 5 questions. I noticed that it had three answers, all with positive scores. Maybe the posse that wants to delete mathematical content from m.se has met up with a posse that wants to preserve mathematical content on m.se.

Comment: Ah yes, the sacrosanct "valid mathematical content". All the content on this website is mathematical, this doesn't mean there isn't any cruft to delete. What makes mathematical content so holy that we don't have any right to delete it, @GerryMyerson? The umpteenth duplicate of "Why 0! = 1?" is mathematical content, must we keep it? How about a crank's attempt to solve the Riemann hypothesis?

Comment: The last of these five should IMO be merged (see my comment under it). May be it should be first reclosed as a dup. I agree with the sentiment of not closing it for "missing context". The second should go as a(n abstract) duplicate (of anything using the same substitution). The quadratic equation should IMO be buried deep as a(n abstract) duplicate. IMO a single question on using the quadratic formula would suffice. If you disagree, make it five. Similar remarks apply to the others, but I don't have the time to take a closer look now.

Comment: @JyrkiLahtonen There is no such thing as "burying deep" when things like Google exist. I'm not able to find it right now, but there was a statement by an SE employee that the majority of people found questions with search engines. People *will* find these questions, and then think they can just input their math homework (without even necessarily taking the time to format anything or put in any effort) and it will be solved quickly.

Comment: Such questions should be closed as [abstract duplicates](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/a/1760) of answers that explain the general method. We cannot afford to have a question with specific solutions for every quadratic equation out there. Such questions add zero value to the site and make it more difficult to find interesting questions. That said, we have no such consensus in the community, and some users want to continue to answer such zero value questions and undelete them when they get deleted.

Comment: The first question does not even really make sense @GerryMyerson, and the issue is still not addressed despite it being pointed out in comments and  an edit happened.

Comment: I'd also like to point out that almost all the recent undeleted questions have been answered by one person, FWIW. @AymanHourieh Questions like that shouldn't just be closed as abstract duplicates, they should be deleted altogether. The answers offer no new insights (how much insight can you have on $\int x e^{x^2} dx$?!), the text of the question is pretty much identical.

Comment: @NajibIdrissi And the undeletions happened by the same group of three. I don't know if this counts as some sort of conflict of interest.

Comment: @NajibIdrissi The point is, 10K+ users should know better than to answer yet another quadratic equation question. We already have excellent answers explaining the general method. Adding an answer, and reopening/undeleting the question (potentially to preserve reputation) is not a positive contribution to the site.

Comment: The mere fact that all were answered by one person is not surprising and more or less alright with me. (One has better access to ones own deleted content than to that of others, even as hig-rep user.) Also that undeletes happened by the same group could be coincidence (after all  after the first vote they are then all in the list), and even if not there is even a semi-official thread for coordination of such efforts whence coordination is alright. My problem is with the quality of the content.

Comment: @AymanHourieh I completely agree with that last comment.

Comment: @NajibIdrissi: The point about google finding these is a good one. But can it also find the deleted threads? 10k+ people can, but I'm uninformed about google's abilities re deleted threads.

Comment: @JyrkiLahtonen As far as I know, no, it cannot find deleted threads. There was a suggestion a while ago that closed questions should be unlisted from search engines, but it wasn't implemented.

Comment: Hm, so you can only vote to close a question once, and I had thought the same probably held for deletions, but apparently [here](http://math.stackexchange.com/q/974943/29335) we learn you can undelete the same question more than once? I'm not saying that's necessarily a terrible idea, but if it is unlimited it is probably broken...

Comment: @rschwieb it is a known issue (though likely not well known); un/delte votes can be recast. There is a thread on MSE, and this came up on MO sometimes in practice: the policy there is that moderators take care of the issue after several iterations by locking the post in the state they feel appropriate. IIRC, it is "by design" only in the sense that nobody cared and cares enough to implement the check that happens for open/close. The MSE ref: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/9431/

Comment: @quid OK, thanks for the update. I was a little worried that a "posse" (apparently the fashionable thing to call groups of people who agree with each other nowadays) of three could hold out indefinitely against 6 or more. But if moderation and locks put a stop to it, that's a good solution IMO.

Comment: @rschwieb you are welcome. I added the MSE thread in the first comment. I agree it can be unfortunate if this starts. Yet also reading the MSE post it seems *if* "we" create enough instances, they might implement the check. A basic throttle is that the global number of del votes is not that high; but still too high for it to be efficient.

Comment: @NajibIdrissi Maybe the last one is different flavor from the rest in that it's "interesting." I'm pretty sure everyone has been tempted to undelete/unclose a question because they "just like the question." It's objectively true that the last question is a PSQ, though. I guess the relatively harmful PSQ's are more like the first four.

Comment: The first revision should not really be a factor here; if *someone* manages to put a question into a respectable form, that's great (be it OP or someone else). This never really happened with the linked posts, though.

Comment: @Behaviour That's true, and the reason why I wrote the rest of the paragraph. (It's funny, every time I open up a controversial meta question, my old questions on main are downvoted... Not enough that it should trigger the auto-reversal, obviously. Not sure what this is supposed to accomplish... /rant)

Comment: @quid: "Also that undeletes happened by the same group could be coincidence..."  There are comments like [this](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/886027/how-do-i-solve-int-frac7-sqrtxx4-mathrmdx#comment1831242_886033) and [this](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1020637/how-do-you-simplify-n3n1-n#comment2086627_1020642), not yet deleted.  I agree with "even if not there is even a semi-official thread for coordination of such efforts whence coordination is alright."

Comment: I have come to consider myself a moderate in the PSQ debate: the line is harder to draw than it first appears. But questions which amount to a single application of the quadratic formula are perfect examples of questions that are obviously and definitively over that line.  They should NOT be allowed on MSE.

Comment: @quid: Unlike reopening votes, undeletion votes do not bump the question. They are fully silent in this aspect. So there is "less" reason to implement this. Closing and reopening can be an ugly way of bumping a question and taking important front-page real estate; but deleting and undeleting is like the fight between the bacteria and antibiotics: unless it's your body, you're unlikely to feel the effects of it. (I leave the reader to choose which are the bacteria, and which are the antibiotics. I have no intentions choosing sides here.)

Comment: "What makes mathematical content so holy that we don't have any right to delete it, @GerryMyerson? The umpteenth duplicate of "Why 0! = 1?" is mathematical content, must we keep it? How about a crank's attempt to solve the Riemann hypothesis?" Najib, I think this is an extraordinarily vituperative response to my comment, in which I simply suggested an answer to your question. I'll try to reply in a restrained manner, to show you how it can be done. Duplicates should of course be closed. If a duplicate gets answered before it's closed, consideration should be given to (continued....)

Comment: @Asaf while this is true  it should be recalled that for all I know close/reopen votes were already restricted at a time when reopening did not yet bump. This discrepancy can thus  not be  grounds for the *original* "design decision."

Comment: ....should be given to merging it with a question it duplicates. Crank attempts at RH, if posted as answers, can be deleted. If posted as questions, and if someone takes the time to compose a thoughtful reply, the question can be closed, but that reply should not be deleted. And which of the 5 questions that prompted your original post contained a crank's attempt to settle the Riemann Hypothesis? Or was your mention of RH just an attempt to muddy the waters, distract attention from the issues, build a strawman?

Comment: @Asaf 10k users can still view it in /tools, fortunately.

Comment: @quid, it's one thing to *close* a *question* that doesn't make sense. It's another thing entirely to *delete* an *answer* that does make sense.

Comment: @GerryMyerson Apart from the tone argument, I only see the statement of your opinion in your comments. Please, forgive me if I get annoyed when I hear the same opinion again and again from the same *posse* without any backing up by arguments. If you're going to be literal like that: where did I state that one of the undeleted questions contained an attempt at solving the Riemann hypothesis, and not just an example of question that, while being mathematical content, should be deleted? Are you trying to put words in my mouth, to build a straw man?

Comment: @quid: Regardless :-) ; **Najib**: (1) don't look, or (2) you're one of the victims of antibiotics and/or the bacteria that suffered (when the body is sick, many parts can be affected. Sometimes by the cure, sometimes by the cause of illness).

Comment: I'm happy to forgive you for getting annoyed, Najib. I'd be even happier to forgive you if you apologized for the tone of your first comment. But the opinions I have expressed in this thread --- which one(s) do you object to? I did say that I'd be happy to see crank attempts at RH deleted. What have I written in this thread that gets you so annoyed?

Comment: @GerryMyerson it seemed to me the question even had reopen votes but it might have been another one. Anyway, it is incomprehensible to me why somebody on the one hand undertakes quite some effort to get that undeleted and at the same time does not care enough to fix the question. Besides keeping unclear questions uncorrected is harmful on many levels. Loosing an answer would be a well-deserved fine for the earlier neglect. It is simple: do not answer poor questions or at least fix them, if not you might loose your answer. This seems simple, fair, and good for the overall quality of the site.

Comment: @quid, I'm not worried about losing *my* answer --- I don't think I had an answer on any of the 5 questions that prompted this discussion. And losing an answer doesn't just punish the person who posted the answer (or the person who posted the question); it punishes anyone who comes to this site looking for the answer. Of course, *you* could go fix those questions, now that they have been undeleted.

Comment: @GerryMyerson the "you" was meant in an impersonal way; I did not mean you personally. Sorry for the confusion. I meant to formulate a general guideline. I should have put that part under quotes. On your further points, on the one hand the question in fact is deleted at the moment, on the other hand *I* do not consider the content worth preserving.  Still I feeel the situation tells something about the main motives of the actors.  Finally, I am pretty sure that abstract/general readers would be helped a lot by much more intense deletion accompanied by consolidating the existing content.

Comment: @quid, here's my take on recent events. Closing crummy questions, after OP has refused the opportunity to improve them, is A Good Thing. Some people have taken this Good Thing too far, by 1) closing questions before OP has had a chance to take on board the need to improve them, 2) voting down mathematically unobjectionable answers, to smooth the way for deletion, and 3) deleting questions that had attracted good answers. Inevitably, this action has led to a reaction, in the form of the undeletions that prompted this thread. Perhaps the undeleters have over-reacted (continued....)

Comment: @GerryMyerson Yes, I'm sorry about the way I replied, that was uncalled for. I still disagree with your position (from what I've gathered, in this meta thread and others before, it is indeed yours; correct me if I'm wrong) that mathematical content (especially in answers) should not be deleted from the website.

Comment: (...continued) by undeleting some material better left deleted, as (in my opinion) the deleters have gone too far in deleting material that shouldn't have been deleted. I think both sides should stand down and take it easy for a while.

Comment: Apology accepted, Najib. My position is that answers should be judged on their own merits, the judgement unpolluted by the quality of the question that led to the answer. When I have become aware that my own answers have been deleted, I have taken a second look at them. When I felt my deleted answer did not contribute much to the site, I did nothing; when I felt my answer did make a contribution, I voted to undelete, or I posted the original question as a new question of my own (with proper attribution), and then posted my answer. So, that's my position.

Comment: @Gerry Meanwhile, the brain drain continues due to these destructive, detestable policies. I just learned that **MSE lost Matt E,** among many other good teachers. That is probably the saddest news I've ever heard here. Looking closer I see MSE has also effectively lost many other superb teachers, who have greatly scaled back their participation as of late. Alas, the site is but a pale shadow of what it used to be.

Comment: @GerryMyerson this seems a reasonable description and point of view. In my opinion, however, there are a lot of answers that while correct and often upvoted, sometimes highly so, are *quite* bad. And, it seems not few do not even realize this. (Not you.) Look at http://math.stackexchange.com/a/1076900/ for example. Is this correct? Maybe if one is extremely generous. Yet I doubt OP of q is served well with that; OP of answer is unresponsive (maybe the dv, cast with considerable delay relative to the comment, will get their attention).

Comment: @quid, I think you have done well in leaving a comment giving your objections to the answer on that question. You have given the person less than 24 hours to respond. Some people just come to m.se once a day. If the person remains unresponsive, well then you've done what you could, go ahead and vote to delete. Or post a better answer!

Comment: @BillDubuque If you just learned this, you might try to pay a bit more attention. Anyway, I fail to see what this  has  to do with the question at hand.

Comment: @GerryMyerson Thank you for your reply. Only, one can see if somebody was online. They were.

Comment: Since Matt E was mentioned, I'll add that he stopped participating in MathOverflow and Math.SE at the same time, in June 2014. Whatever his reason was, it is not specific to this site.

Comment: @Behaviour Not necessarily. Look at all the destruction you have caused by initiating this campaign. How sad.

Comment: @Behaviour Perhaps you forgot that June 2014 was the time when your massive downvoting and deletion campaign started gathering full steam, and started being widely exposed (e.g. in [this meta question](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/q/15126/242) among other places), right around the same time Matt E. completely ceased participation.

Comment: @Behaviour what you say is a bit misleading while technically true. Matt Emerton essentially stopped to use MO way earlier; his last answer was posted three years ago. He continued to post comments here an there and did some voting but basically he was gone since end of 2011.  (It should be quite clear I do not agree with BD but still I wanted to clear this up.)

Comment: @Behaviour Further it is certainly not true that Matt ceased participation on MO at the same time. His newest answer on MO is 3 years ago (Nov 21, 2011). His only MO activity this past year are a few comments and tag edits. But he was *very active* on MSE till June 2014, giving some of the most insightful answers on the site.

Comment: @BillDubuque while you are correct re Matt E leaving MO earlier (and you can see I even mentioned it before you) it seems a bit far fetched to link a meta thread started 29 june to Matt E leaving June 16. Further, if one wants to look for a specific motivation it seems more reasonable to take the one where it is clear he was not at all happy with both sites very close to him leaving, namely the events around Makoto Kato. But *I* do not know. Anyway, various users leave for various and completely contradictory reasons.

Comment: @quid Those events started becoming known in early-to-mid June, so the timing is spot-on.

Comment: @BillDubuque there are users that made quite clear why they left, why they never joined (I mean MO users never joining here), why they made a break and so on. If you are interested in a serious discussion about users' motivations we might try to compile public statements on that matter and proceed from there. Idle speculations on an isolated case, based on vague temporal coincidences, are not constructive, especially when the main point seems to be finger-pointing to support your current position. Let me add, indeed there are some such statements that support your position but not at all all.

Comment: @quid I suppose you'll also argue that it is pure coincidence that Matt's final meta activities had to do with attempts to undelete some posts. Based on what Matt wrote on these and related meta matters, I have little doubt why he left. Not only is it a great loss to lose his mathematical wisdom, but also his interpersonal skills. He was a great voice of reason on meta - surely a role model for incoming mods.

Comment: @BillDubuque There is nothing in your last comment with which I disagree specifically, my point that discussing isolated cases in the way you do is not constructive still stands.

Comment: The continuing antics of Did, and  Behavior (??) should be noted.

Comment: Whether W|A can answer a question is irrelevant; it doesn’t offer explanations.

Comment: @quid: *Finally, I am pretty sure that abstract/general readers would be helped a lot by much more intense deletion accompanied by consolidating the existing content.* I’m not. It isn’t even true of me. The only consolidation that’s worth a damn is the consolidation of genuine duplicates so as to get all of the answers more or less in one place, and we do a halfway decent job of that when we remember that a duplicate exists.

Comment: @Ayman: While I would very rarely (if ever) answer a routine question about solving a quadratic using the quadratic equation, it is simply not true that having a good general explanation of something is sufficient. Students all too often need help applying even a good general explanation to the first specific problem or two. The idea of abstract duplicates was a bad one from the beginning.

Comment: @Brian Alas, I realized long ago that the SE platform does not have the capability to properly handle abstract duplicates (it doesn't even properly handle exact duplicates given the woefully inadequate merge tools). That's why I never fleshed out the proposal (which was meant to handle the issues you mention). My thoughts on duplicates have changed dramatically since [my post 3 years ago](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/q/1756/242) - so much that they may not differ much from yours.

Comment: The situation would be much improved if certain answerers spent a tiny bit of time searching for duplicates. The high volume tags: high school level, Elementary number theory and Calculus are possibly the worst offenders in this regard with prolific "crank-turners" exacerbating the problem by adding legitimacy to those questions. I find it reprehensible that 10k+ members take the approach of "Answer first and leave checking of duplicates to others".

Comment: @Brian I agree that many students have problems applying a technique spelled out in an example to their problem. But my 25 years of teaching experience, though less than your 40, also have taught to me that the problems those learners have run deeper. Having one more example explained to them is not going to make them see the light, because the gaps in their background won't allow them to add that piece of knowledge to the big picture of this beautiful jigsaw puzzle. Fixing that is the job of their teachers/tutors, and cannot IMHO be adequately done in Math.SE.

Comment: And I know that Brian does his very best in trying to explain as opposed to "turn the crank". I disagree with him about how effective that will be in the confines of Math.SE. But that remains to be seen. These questions simply attract useless crank-turning, which is why I am aggressively closing them.

Comment: @Bill: Will you please open your new and superawesome platform already? I'm sure that everyone will be excited to join it if it's as good as you say that it is. It's been two years since you've said "soon" the first time on this issue. How much more do we have to suffer in this horrible horrible site, where teachers are forced to teach people who may or may not want to learn, and students are forced not to have their questions answered unless they are trying to learn from the answers, and people come to your house and force you at gunpoint to post answers on set theory tags... SAVE US!

Comment: @Brian Definitely, examples are crucial for good understanding. This is why a canonical answer should contain some examples in addition to the general theory. Here is a canonical answer on [integration by partial fractions](http://math.stackexchange.com/a/21112); it contains plenty of examples. I think students would learn a lot more if they were referred to this question, as opposed to seeing their particular exercise solved for them. Alas, some of our 10K+ are willing to answer hundreds of such questions, adding very little value to the site, and burying good questions in the process.

Comment: @BrianM.Scott I am sorry but I do not  understand at all what you mean by "it is not *even* true for me" (my emphasis). The site is full of answers that are quite poor in my opinion; it is also full of answers that are quite good. *I* have little problem navigating this, neither do you I assume. However, the "even" makes no sense in this context. Further, some answer are terse to the extent of being cryptic. This can be amusing to read, if it is ones style and one gets the "hint," and this is witness by the votes.

Comment: Yet again this is amusing if either one understands it or has no actual need. Again, the "even" makes no sense. My main issue with all this is the quality of the answers. The current state of affairs gives, in various ways, very strong incentives to write "quick-and-dirty" answers, some of the still helpful, some not so much, some even harmful. Once again your "even" makes no sense to me as you hardly need the answers here for anything specific I assume. @BrianM.Scott

Comment: One more point @BrianM.Scott I cannot double check ATM but hope to recall it correctly: my main issue with the quadratic equation answer, for example, is that it did not even bother to state (right away) that in this cases the discriminant vanishes. Really this is the main thing to highlight there, as it is not uncommon that students are thrown of by degenerate cases. It was not. Why? Either because the relevance is not clear (which would be somewhat legitimate), or since answerer did not even bother to check.

Comment: @quid: Of course it makes sense. I have on more than a few occasions used MSE as a source of information on a mathematical topic, both deliberately and simply because it turned up on a general search, and I have not been in the least discommoded by lack of consolidation or proliferation of material of no interest to me, despite the fact that I am more likely than the average user to benefit from questions and answers of the type that you prefer.

Comment: @BrianM.Scott if you have an interest to understand my POV I'd ask you to base your reply on what I write and not some preconceived notion of  "questions and answers of the type that [I] prefer." I'm unhappy not about the level of the q but about a lack of quality, detail,  care, and adaption to the actual situation at hand in many answers (especially to low level q). This is not much of a problem for you and I, but it could be for readers that actually need an answer to that question. I simply want **better** answers. I want pearls, yet the culture of this site mainly produces sand.

Comment: @quid: I did base my answer on what you’ve written. It does not seem to me that your writing on the subject is entirely consonant with the assertion that you simply want better answers; perhaps you fail to recognize some of the consequences of your approach to getting better answers.

Comment: @BrianM.Scott what is "my approach"?

Comment: My guess as to why Matt E stopped participating on the Stack Exchange network is that, as a part of an annual tradition, he was the subject of a little parody by UChicago grad students ([YouTube link](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=fGh3AoW-JlU)). Note that this occurred on June 6, 2014. However, no one can know for sure - in the meantime, maybe certain users should stop trying to use anyone's departure from this site for their own agenda.

Comment: Open, upvoted vitriolic hatred against a nemesis; lots of arrogant big words; extreme elitism of the I Have a Dream and if you disagree do go away sort...this is the most unpleasant comment thread I have seen on this site, and yes, I followed several of the old wars or words. It's funny that this comment (like earlier ones I made) is more likely to be flagged or deleted than any of the above hostility, as I don't frequent chat, and don't write in legalese.

Comment: @gnometorule Thanks for the spectacularly nonconstructive comment.

Comment: @gnometorule a problem with your comment could be that everybody can read it their way. It is honestly not clear to me what you refer to at each point.

Comment: @someone Thanks for the chuckles. Of course it doesn't change my opinion on the matter (though I doubt it was seriously intended to).

Comment: @NajibIdrissi: Does the last example really illustrate your point?  I looked at the edit history, and it seems the original post was substantially the problem posed by the current (closed) version.  Although it can be addressed by elementary number theory, it hardly qualifies as *garbage*, as evidenced by Jyriki's comment on the Question and three distinguishable Answers.

Answer (score 22):

This continues to be a divisive issue with neither side willing to compromise at all. Mathematicians being idealists of the purest kind that is hardly a surprise.

I am somewhat impressed by the fact that hardly anyone is bringing up reputation in this discussion. In spite of our love/hate relationship with these internet points the rep game is a strong driving force here. Oversimplified: As we cannot change the fact that everybody's upvotes give the same +10 rep, the problem with easy PSQs persists

- one faction is seen by the other as protecting their ego point gravy train, and
- one faction is seen by the other as wanting to levy high taxes on the Joneses instead of keeping up with them (simple jealousy comes to mind also).

Some posters are blaming Behaviour's campaign for the current state of the affairs. That is IMO another oversimplification. The sentiment against LHF/PSQ/HW/whathever you want to call them (and their FGITW answers) had been growing for a long time. Behaviour was simply the first to find a way of attacking these that actually managed to make a dent to that wall. When T. Bongers brought the matter up in Meta, it had the (possibly unintended) consequence that many members who were unhappy about the situation (raises hand) realized that they actually have efficient Tools to fight the problem. The deletion of PSQs then picked up speed.

This caused a change in the site dynamics. The prolific answerers had gotten used to nothing ever disappearing. As it was a statistical certainty that even their answers (many objectively quite good, but to objectively bad questions) would become collateral damage, the change naturally came as a shock. This was evidenced in André's outburst. Undeniably IT WAS A CHANGE - the site became a bit different. And conservatives are never happy with a change. Do remember that the increase in the frequency of PSQs was also a change. But that was a more gradual change, and had to reach a certain point to make conservatives of a different kind come out in the open.

Of course, at the same time the defenders of those questions also learned about the tools. Deletion/undeletion wars have commenced. I predict that we will be behaving like kids for quite some time still, fighting for territory in this sandbox. Eventually an uneasy truce will be reached - in the form of a thermal equilibrium between delete/undelete votes. But we are not there yet.

---

I have also been toying with the following

**GEDANKENEXPERIMENT:**

- The pro-deletion party ceases deletion of PSQs for a time being, and instead flags the PSQs to moderators' attention upon sight, and
- the moderators turn the PSQs into Community Wiki -questions.

This has the known effect of eliminating reputation gains from such questions. With ego points removed from the equation, we can then test, who is sincere and who is not. The possible outcomes are:

1. Nobody bothers to answer a CWified elementary question, but the complaints about PSQs continue. Case proven - the answerers were only doing it for the sake of internet points, and the anti-PSQ party wins.
2. The answers continue to come in, but the complaints stop. Case proven - the complaints were only about internet points, not really about the quality of site. The pro-PSQ party wins.
3. No answers + no complaints. Everybody should be ashamed.
4. The steady stream of answers continues as do the complaints. This is IMHO the best possible outcome, because everybody learns that the other side is sincere. May be mutual respect will begin to grow?

---

Of course, there's the alternative to acknowledge that you (yes, I mean you, my dear reader) **cannot have it all your way.** The sooner we realize this (yours truly included) the better off we collectively are.

---

Bill is probably right in that the site software cannot be bent to handle *abstract duplicates* well. I think that collecting/merging existing abstract duplicates to Community Wiki threads is the best available approximation. The merging will necessitate quite a bit of editing by hand. Martin has been hard at work already (see his links under this) - sans CWification. If elected I could also give it a try. I would start by listing a representative sample of questions, move the answers to the umbrella thread, and edit in the number of the specific example handled in that answer. Unfortunately the amount of work may be overwhelming, and I'm not sure about whether that is a satisfactory resolution.

---

Moi? Confession time! I know that it is silly to worry about internet points, but I'm not completely at peace with the fact that noobs here think that (for example) Lab Bhattacharjee is twice the mathematician that I am, because he has accumulated twice the rep.  Against that the same noobs may think I know more than, say, David Speyer or Noam D. Elkies, which is just ridiculous. Sue me! This may be a good reason for me to run for a moderator position in that I lose the power to cast delete votes on contentious threads.

Comment: *I think that collecting/merging existing abstract duplicates to Community Wiki threads is the best available approximation.* It is probably not exactly the same thing as you have in mind, but I have tried to create some threads collecting frequently asked questions. See [this post on meta](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/3967/would-organizer-posts-be-useful-welcome-here).

Comment: Thanks, @Martin. We should do that in main, too.

Comment: Well, the post [I've made so far](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/3967/would-organizer-posts-be-useful-welcome-here/4071#4071) are posted on the main. The meta posts only contains the list of posts. (Although very short.)

Comment: I agree that answering PSQs is often driven by reputation. However, I have an observation to make. Most votes on PSQs happen early on during the question's life cycle. Reputation already earned isn't taken back when the question is converted to CW. I don't think that flagging and manual conversion to CW would be quick enough. Answering PSQ would remain an effective way for harvesting reputation.

Comment: @AymanHourieh: Yes, that is a problem. We would need to have several moderators working on this. Also users commenting and voting to steer the development in this direction. Needs more work.

Comment: The CW suggestion is interesting. My main objection has been to the campaign to make answers disappear.

Comment: Raking my brain and trying to find a way for the two factions to co-exist somewhat peacefully. I know that this suggestion doesn't address all the relevant concerns. And as an anti-PSQ activist I may be the wrong guy to suggest anything and call it a "compromise". Also this probably means using CW in an unintended way. Thank you for the voices of support. Ideas for improvement?

Comment: (a) "Ceases deletion" is a non-starter. My votes are not something I negotiate over. (b) Having users routinely raise mod-only flags is an unsustainable workflow. (c) Since P(reward) will remain strictly between 0 and 1, as it is now, those motivated by points will keep  answering. (d) I do believe that many of those answering are driven by genuine desire to help, so they will keep on answering.

Comment: Hence, (e): SE needs to recognize that deletion/undeletion wars are in fact possible, and [add a check for repeat votes](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/9431/), as they did for closevotes. Mods can lend their support to the feature through Mod-SE team channel if they perceive this a real issue for the site.

Comment: @Behaviour: Thanks for the comments. Your suggestion is one possible future (if the repeat votes are disabled) that will resolve the disputes by vox populi. I was hoping that after a learning period the regulars (on both sides of the aisle) would know when not to bother unless one braces for a delete/undelete war. Not ruling out the possibility that a similar uneasy truce would emerge out of your approach, too.

Comment: Let me contest the "internet point" issue. I have a real world reputation as "that choice guy" or "that guy who answers set theory questions on MSE" particularly because I have these internet points, earned by answering all those set theory questions. These points might be nearly meaningless, but they carry meaning to real life in some sense.

Answer (score -4):

PSQ are only an issue when they boil down to doing someones homework for them. If the hypothetical hand-in deadline has passed, and someone makes an effort to improve the post, then there is no reason for the question to be closed. To back this point up, the StackExchange model is built on [editing](http://blog.stackoverflow.com/2009/04/in-defense-of-editing/) - noone "owns" a question, and so the original form should not matter, no matter how poorly the original question was formed.

All the posts you link to are over a month old. Therefore, (in theory<sup>†</sup>) I have no qualms about undeleting these and similar questions.

---

<sup>†</sup> [This one](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/974943/solve-9x230x25-0-using-quadratic-formula) is still odd. I probably wouldn't cast a vote either way. The questions should still meet the minimum standards, whatever you or I or whoever is voting deem them to be.

Comment: There now it's elevated. The main problem with PSQ isn't just the OP getting the solution to their homework in time. It's also the filling of the site with low quality questions, and then people finding these questions via Google and thinking the site is a homework factory. They also haven't been answered just today, they were answered immediately after being asked. If they had been answered today, they would have taken frontpage space from other, more deserving questions. There have been dozens and dozens of meta threads about it, I'm not going to repeat everything here.

Comment: The first question, for example, makes no sense as written. This was even mentioned in a comment very early on. This does not meet my minimum standard.

Comment: @Najib You seem to be saying two things - firstly, that the issue is with people answering these questions immediately, and secondly that these questions are "low quality". Well, for point (1), why not delete the answers? And for point (2), math.SE is not a journal - a question does not need to be vetted for mathematical significance before being asked. They [do not need to be hard](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/9239).

Comment: Also, define "low quality"? I rather like [this](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1027680) question. It is a really pretty problem - it is...deserving. But the person who posed it didn't give context and yadda yadda yadda DELETE!

Comment: (1) I don't have the privilege to delete answers yet; what's the point in keeping questions that shouldn't be answered?; answering *immediately* isn't the only problem, if you read my comments again you'll see that I give arguments why. (2) They don't need to be vetted before being asked, but we can delete them if they don't meet the website's standards. I'm not sure what your point is here.

Comment: I don't want to discuss it again if you have no new arguments to make, no. The arguments I've given here have already been spelled out in much more detail in previous meta threads, I'm just giving them again for some perspective. But discussing it again seems like a waste of time if no new perspective is given.

Comment: My point about (2) is that "easy" questions are not easy to everyone. Last week I had a student get 1 mark out of 80 in their final exam. 1 mark! And yet because this student is struggling with basic stuff, they will not find any help here. Not if your deletion votes have anything to say about it. And yet, this is the student who needs the most help.

Comment: This is *not* a "help site."

Comment: With your response to (1): then do not vote. Let people who have 20k vote to delete the answers. If you believe that what you are doing is just, then have confidence in your belief. And the questions are not questions which "should not be answered", rather they are questions "which should not be answered immediately".

Comment: @quid It is a site which answers students maths questions. If you ask a sufficiently well-posed question, someone will help you with it. That is all I mean when I say "help" - I do not mean "walked through" or anything like that. I just mean...help.

Comment: You seem to be mixing up "quality" and "difficulty". A question does not have to be difficult for it to be worth answering. (FYI I do not receive a notification if you do not include something like "@Najib" in your comment -- it's helpful if you're directly talking to me...)

Comment: @Najib I was assuming that by "quality" you meant "difficulty". My point - the entire point of my answer- is that if the quality of the question can be brought up to a sufficient level then *the question should be reopened* (so long as a sufficient time has passed).

Comment: The site does not only answer *students* math questions. It answers questions of everybody able to ask a proper question. This might not include all students (not even in tertiarty education), which, while quite unfortunate, is not a problem to be solved *here*. In addition, the quality of not few answers is such that a student, especially a weak student, might be better of without them. Let us better work on this aspect.

Comment: @Najib: The fact remains that easy questions not infrequently quickly attract downvotes and votes to close *no matter how they are formulated*. It is quite clear that some users *do* to a large extent subsume *easy* under *low quality*.

Comment: @Brian I certainly think that way. I don't think I have ever been hiding the fact that IMO the proliferation of easy PSQs is exactly what is wrong with the PSQs in the first place.

Comment: @Bill I find the suggestion that Matt Emerton stopped participating, because low level questions are getting deleted quite hilarious. IIRC he was not seen answering those. Why do you keep bringing up the absence of such members in this context? You have blamed the anti-PSQ party, in turn, for the absence of Arturo Magidin, Brian M. Scott and now Matt E. This is pure speculation, and also a strawman. Do you want me to list names of people no longer active, who I suspect to have left because the site is ovewhelmed by trivial things?

Comment: @JyrkiLahtonen I don't agree. I get quite frustrated at the double-standard where calculus PSQs get insta-closed, while questions quite obviously copy-pasted from graduate or late-undergraduate level problem sets on Galois theory, symplectic geometry, algebraic topology etc. get dozens of upvotes and spoon-fed answers.

Comment: I see your point @user7530. I am somewhat guilty of that myself - see [item 3 here](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/a/9292/11619). As much as I would like the answers to Galois theory, algebraic topology, functional analysis etc questions to produce as much rep as the elementary ones, I don't see that happening. Double-standard? Possibly? That may be one "bargaining chip" in this equation. But I don't see the site overwhelmed with questions by upperclassmen either. Statistically there should be the same number of math juniors (or seniors) as freshmen. We have failed to attract them here?

Comment: And while we are at it, why do **answers** obviously copy/pasted from textbooks get a lot of upvotes ;-)

Comment: @Jyrki: The activities of the anti-PSQ party were in fact one of the main reasons for my departure. And given the deliberate vandalism that apparently started last June, I'm not at all sure how long I'll stick it out this time around. \\ Far more people take freshman-level math courses than take upper-division math courses, so of course we get more elementary questions. Why on earth would you expect similar numbers statistically?!

Comment: @Brian I know that US is different from us, but apparently forgot. Yet I don't think the numbers of questions at various levels reflect the numbers of students taking math seriously at various levels. Admittedly that is difficult to substantiate. Anyway, the point that we are not overwhelmed by low effort point-set topology or Galois theory questions still stands. Vandalism? The flood of  low level questions is also seen as a form of vandalism. And some members actively encourage it.

Comment: More importantly: How would you resolve the problem that those who detest freshman/high school problems are extremely unhappy? Your opposite numbers are equally unwilling to compromise. Without a compromise the site will split in two. I don't see any other way, if people continue to take this uncompromising "my way or highway" stand.

Comment: @Jyrki: By leaving, if their views prevail. My preferences may inconvenience them a bit, but theirs actually restrict my choices.

Comment: @user7530 This is the effect we've observed where the reader's fondness for a particular question occludes the negative aspects of the question. I think everyone is going to do this at some point, so it seems we'll have to be sympathetic.

Comment: Brian: That makes me sad. There have also been good contributors who felt that allowing such questions is a dealbreaker. So it is not just an *inconvenience*. I don't want to speculate on the names and numbers, because that does not really help here.

Comment: @user1729: I have seen the likes of your 1/80 scoring student. My experience suggest that such students have serious gaps in their background. Math being a cumulative subject and all that. We do apply the spiral method when teaching, but someone a few full laps behind needs to work on their background - review lower level textbooks and all that. I don't think that such a student can be adequately helped by a few sporadic answers here. I often engage in longish exchanges on our site, but such a chain of Q&As can only reach so far back.

Comment: All: Conceding Brian's point about the relative frequencies of students at various levels. I was simply wrong about that.

Comment: @JyrkiLahtonen Please show some integrity. If you wish to attack my position, then do so by explicitly quoting things that I have actually said, not something that you have pulled out of thin air.

Comment: While I knew that for @BrianM.Scott the assertion that he had taken a break due to such activities is correct, it would be blatantly false for Arturo Magidin. Indeed there is a comment by him on meta.MO where he explains that it was in fact the *anti* anti-PSQ/HW activity that annoyed him most.

Comment: @Jyrki: The fact that they considered it a dealbreaker does not raise it above the level of an inconvenience: the fact is that it did not restrict their activity, and they did wish to impose actual restrictions on mine.

Comment: @quid Neither I (nor anybody iirc)  made any such claims (esp. about Arturo). Jyrki's claim is unfounded, yet another strawman attack (which, alas, is par for the course on meta these days). I find it qite troubling that a number of mod candidates professed having troubles emphasizing and understanding the positions of others. This is perhaps the most serious problem on meta these days - that here is little hope of having rational arguments because many folks make no reasonable efforts to comprehend the essence of their opponents positions.

Comment: @BillDubuque I do not recall a particular instance either, but I did not follow this site here all the time so it does not tell that much. Anyway, I hope you noted that I wrote that it "would be blatantly false" (as opposed to "is blatantly false") precisely for this reason. To mention it still seemed pertinent in a context where for better or worse various users' motives are mention.

Comment: [continued from above] Instead, due to severe addictions to the upvote drug, meta is littered with many simplistic FGITW strawmen arguments guaranteed to gain upvotes, and feed the addiction. The irony of the matter is that these posts are precisely the meta analog of the behavior that the authors attack on main. But to realize that takes a bit of introspection - something that takes too much time from those in search of yet another upvote (at any expense). The cancer created by SE is in full bloom.

Comment: @BillDubuque  "Upvote addition" on a site where rep doesn't count? Equating a large body of low quality questions with the complaints about them? Let's all just bask in the absurdity of that for a while.

Comment: @rschwieb I cannot make any sense of your prior comment.

Comment: @BillDubuque I also have an honest request. Please stop bemoaning the "cancer of SE" and that it is "a shadow of what it once was" and various other elaborate and unconstructive gripes about today's math.SE. I think we can stand the wild theories, the debate team handbook dismissals, the equivocation and other tools of desperation you need to fight against the large chorus of opposition, but next time you feel like taking a universal dump on the site, and trampling all of the good work that's been done in spite of the site's problems,just pass it up.

Comment: @rschwieb Gripes about gamification, despicable debating, and highly destructive constraints on teaching is hardly "trampling all of the good work that's been done".

Comment: @BillDubuque Please pay attention to the examples. I am not referring to complaints like that. I hope and expect everyone to continue following their conscience to complain. I gave specific examples of the type of generic doom and gloom that we can do without, and they had nothing to do with gamification, debating or constraints. The point is to *stop making melodramatic comments that sow negativity.* They don't help, and they do disparage the hard work of those who work to make the site good *today.*

Comment: @rschwieb The claims are not meant to be "generic". Rather, they are founded on the specific items mentioned (here and elsewhere). We simply disagree about the severity of the problems, and the effects those problems will have on the site.