# What are the merits, if there is any, of deleting (correctly) answered questions in the main site of MSE?

Tags: discussion, deletion

**Note 2**: †

This is NOT a duplicate of the linked question: I am NOT asking at all "[Under what circumstances is it appropriate to delete a question that has received a good answer?](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/16462/9464)" Again, this post is NOT about when or whether we should delete a question, NO. It is a discussion about the *merits* of deleting answered questions in the main site.

† [Added for responding to a close vote.](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/posts/29972/revisions)

---

**Note 1**:

This is **NOT** a duplicate of the suggested link ([Requests for Reopen & Undeletion Votes (volume 07/2018 - today)](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/28692/requests-for-reopen-undeletion-votes-volume-07-2018-today)) at all. While I disagree with the linked questions below being deleted, this post is **NOT** about voting to undeleting or reopening questions at all, **NO**!

Rather, I am seeking a general explanation/discussion of why such deletion is (or could be) of value to the main site of MSE.

---

[Original question.]

I have noticed recently that quite a lot of *answered* questions, some of which are still "on-hold", are being deleted by mostly a small group of users in the [chat room CRUDE](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/info/2165/crude):

- [If $p$ is an odd prime and $k$ an integer with $0<k<p-1$ then $1^k + 2^k + \ldots + (p-1)^k$ is divisible by $p$](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/1777526/9464) (now undeleted, 2 deleted votes)
- [How many of these lines lie entirely in the interior of the original cube?](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/3148006/9464) (now undeleted, 1 close vote)
- [how to show that $F(t)$ is a periodic function with period T](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/1879690/9464) (now undeleted, 1 deleted vote)
- [Counting of natural numbers that have certain properties](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/3142569/9464) (now undeleted, 1 close vote)
- [IMC 2011 question involving six tangent circles](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/3132622/9464) (now undeleted, 1 close vote)
- [Find the number of ways to select two balls of different color through combinations](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/3107610/9464) (now undeleted, 1 delete vote)
- [If $p<q$, then $qx \equiv c \pmod{p}$ has a solution.](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/3142976/9464)(deleted)
- [Finding an angle in a triangle?](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/3134798/9464) (deleted)

I highly doubt the justification of such deletion since it makes others' work (mostly) disappear. A (very) high-rep user (now no longer active) had a similar concern for such action before:

[Is there an MSE-like site that is more pleasant to work in? Or are there other solutions?](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/16451/9464)

**Question**:

> What are the merits, if there is any, of deleting (correctly) answered questions in the main site of MSE?

Comment: Related: [Deleting questions with answers](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/28168/deleting-questions-with-answers), [Why would a question with an upvoted and accepted answer be deleted?](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/29766/why-would-a-question-with-an-upvoted-and-accepted-answer-be-deleted) and [Under what circumstances is it appropriate to delete a question that has received a good answer?](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/16462/under-what-circumstances-is-it-appropriate-to-delete-a-question-that-has-receive)

Comment: You should probably be a clearer about what you want to achieve by poking this bear.  Are you in favour of any answered question, no matter how ill-posed or against the 'good question' guidelines being kept?  Are you in favour of a certain subset of them (please describe how that subset should be determined)?  Are you complaining about what you perceive as organised behaviour (a cartel, perhaps?)?  The merits, if they are such, are easily found as YuiTo Cheng has pointed out.

Comment: I also notice that you've recently edited the 'how to ask a good question' thread.  Are the changes you've made there relevant to this question, perhaps?

Comment: @postmortes: "The merits, if they are such, are easily found as YuiTo Cheng has pointed out." Then I suggest you put them into an answer. I do not find it easy to find.

Comment: The main merit, as I see it, is that it discourages users from answering do-my-homework posts. It's easy to understand how a new user comes here, sees thousands upon thousands of low-quality copy-paste questions answered, and thinks that they can follow along - deleting these posts is a token effort towards correcting that assumption. The only harm that I see is to the pride of the answerers… and to their reputation scores.

Comment: "The main merit, as I see it, is that it discourages users from answering do-my-homework posts." -- I wonder if there's any sort of statistics that could be somehow obtained that verify how useful closing/deleting such questions is. As frequently as they pop up, one would argue it doesn't help, or at least doesn't do enough to stem the flow of such question. Of course, I haven't been around long enough to have witnessed a period before such a policy on PSQs/etc., so maybe it was just WAY worse back then (if there was a "back then"). Makes me wonder if there's anything else we could do though.

Comment: I find very unfair to delete answered questions (no matter what kind of question) I know that do-my-homework questions or psq questions are not allowed because of the rules of the site, but in the end the answer it's valuable _knowledge_. It's also not right that if you put a bounty on a do-my-homework post, then no one argues about it. I mean, even one mod said once to not to flag a do-my-homework post or psq question if this one has a bounty...

Comment: @Isa the value of knowledge lies in its applicability: knowing the maximum percentage of oxygen permissable in air before oxygen-toxicity becomes a problem is valuable knowledge, but arguably not on this site :)  Your comment about bountying a do-my-homework post probably deserves its own question.

Comment: @postmortes It's [here](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/29951/what-happens-if-you-flag-a-question-with-bounty)

Comment: @Saad I think the OP doesn't just want to undelete specific questions mentioned in his post; Rather, he wants a general explanation of why deletion is of value to this site.

Comment: @YuiToCheng It might be so had there not been so many "example posts."

Comment: After I posted this question, two of my old (more than one year) well-received questions are downvoted and one being voted to be closed. As an experienced user who has asked and answered hundreds of questions, I certainly know what such behavior of sudden labeling of other's work as a so-called PSQ means.

Comment: @Jack Similar to the OP of [Kafkaesque question closure(s)](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/29945/kafkaesque-question-closures)

Comment: @YuiToCheng: While they may be relevant (thanks for the links), I have explicitly asked a general question that none of those posts has such scope.

Comment: @postmortes all the do-my-homework post are about mathematics so it belongs here in this site, I know some of these might be very silly or trivial ones for certain users but could be very introductory for beginners.

Comment: @Isa I think that's what the debate is about: whether this really is a site to get your homework done for you

Comment: @postmortes (: noo. that's not what the debate is about, see Jack's update

Comment: @Isa If the site isn't about getting your homework done then it will be hard for anyone to argue that PSQs shouldn't be deleted.  Jack's update doesn't change the underlying argument that's been on this site for a long time

Comment: @postmortes When the PSQs has an answer then just let it be in this site, should not be deleted bacause someone spend time answering and it's correct. when the PSQ is alone then fine, delete it

Comment: It's like the bounty PSQ, they just let the question remain there.

Comment: @Isa write an answer please, comments are not for discussion

Comment: @postmortes I'd like but I have to go, someone has 1,000 activities to do today.

Comment: @postmortes I disagree with both "that's what the debate is about" and "it will be hard for anyone to argue that PSQs shouldn't be deleted" (we are talking about *past, already answered* PSQs, not new ones. The debate is rather "*is deleting those past, answered, closed questions an efficient way to prevent new ones (PSQs, HW, etc) appearing*"

Comment: And I don't think the answer is that clear. As mentioned as a comment to quid's answer, the OPs of these closed answered questions are probably not coming back anyway, so it won't affect them. Newcomers won't see the deleted questions, so won't learn from their closure/erasure. The only argument is that it will deter the **answerers**... but again, that's for stuff they answered 5 months or 5 years ago, so... really? Instead of changing their future behavior, that might just piss them off and drive them away (and thus also lead to fewer *good* answers on *good* questions)

Comment: I am adding one more upvote - not necessarily to imply that I agree with the post, but simply to get it to the score $+3$, which is the cut-off for being shown in the community bulletin. This might increase that likelihood that more users notice this discussion and contribute to it.

Comment: And... The post has been deleted, marked as duplicate in spite of disclaimers explaining why and how it differed from suggested "duplicates." Well, it's nice to have conversations while they (are allowed to) last, I gather?

Comment: Sorry, "closed" (not deleted). Wrong word, and that of course matters -- in that context especially.

Comment: Seems like that's been rectified by now. ... Not sure why people were voting to close despite the clear indications that this was not a duplicate but whatever. @ClementC.

Answer (score 16):

Deletion sends a rather clear message that the content is not welcome. To send this message is a merit of deletion. By contrast to put on hold/close yet not delete does not achieve much especially for answered questions.

Of course, one might think that the content is or should be welcome, but that would be a separate concern. If one wishes to discuss this, then one should start a step earlier namely question the closures.

Comment: Logically one might welcome an Answer's content while objecting to a Question's content, so the OP may have intentionally broached the issue at the step of deletion.  But +1 for addressing the purpose of deleting content.

Comment: The main point of closing is to prevent answers from being given. It seems not quite coherent to me to be in favor of preventing answers to a question yet at the same time being in favor of preserving the answers that in one's opinion should not have been given in the first place. At least as a general approach. (There can be corner-cases.)

Comment: But.... that's not going to be effective, right? Recent "previously-closed but now-deleted" questions (at least the latest two I have seen) are by *new users*, who didn't know the rules before asking, got an answer, and are now probably never coming back. So deleting the question entirely erases it for all future newcomers (they can't see it), and thus... they will repeat the same pattern?

Comment: @Clement at least it is more effective than trying to come up with a hw policy which we failed for several years.

Comment: @ArcticChar Is it though? (see my answer). What if the only outcome is "pretty much as many bad questions asked, but valuable contributors driven away"?

Comment: @ClementC. to a considerable extent the message is intended for those that *answered* the question. Note that OP insists on answered questions.

Comment: -1: this answer overlooks the fact the mentioned content is "not welcome" by an active **minority** of users. Unless one tracks their activities the majority of users do not get to see the deletion of answered questions, often years after the fact. As we see here in meta, when such a case is presented openly, it is very common for the deletion decision to be reversed by the majority. So we do have an issue, in that a minority is destroying content, technically in the open, but in practice under wraps.

Comment: @MartinArgerami "it is very common for the deletion decision to be reversed by the majority" those that vote to undelete on any regular basis to me seem to be  just as much a minority. Do you have any basis to claim that this is a *majority*?  Majority of what even? In actual fact the vast majority of users does not seem to care much either way.

Comment: Further it's not really clear in what sense the answer overlooks this (even if it were true). Those that delete presumably want to send that message. That's the reason for, viz merit of, deleting. Obviously if one is in favor of the content there is no merit in deleting it, that much seems trivial. @MartinArgerami

Comment: @quid: what message? It often happens that not even the person whose answer is deleted learns about the deletion. It's plain destruction of content, with no message.

Comment: @MartinArgerami first, I am still waiting for an explanation regarding "majority." Until this is given it stays hollow rhetoric. Second, what you say might be true for some deletions of old content. Mostly it seems that question is  about deletions of more recent content which usually are noted (via the loss of points).

Comment: Finally, given the constant stream of complaints almost exclusively by those that created the content, clearly it's noted and not appreciated. Whence the message works as intended. That might sound cynical, but that's how it is.

Comment: @MartinArgerami Your perception may be different from mine, but judging from what I have seen, the active users of C.R.U.D.E. are also among the most active reopen/undelete voters. The site has always been self-correcting iin CRUD-matters, which is the way it is supposed to be, by design! I may be misinterpreting your position, but I suspect your resentment comes from unfamiliarity with the semi-automatic nature of these processes as well as their reversals.

Comment: (cont'd) Granted, there is some asymmetry in that closures, and also deletions, get a lot of space in C.R:U.D.E. This reflects the fact that closures are often urgent - deletions less so but speed amplifies the message. In contrast, we can take our time deliberating reopenings and undeletions. If/when a closed post is edited, that gets also advertised in the chat. But, a sad fact is that neither askers nor answerers rarely bother to do anything. Consequently the suggestions for reversals of the initial judgement are outnumbered by the posts pointing out problematic material.

Comment: To add to @JyrkiLahtonen comment, in which he notes that closures and deletions seem to be the most prevalent sort of activity on CRUDE, this is almost certainly expected:  in order for a question to be eligible for closure, it must simply exist.  In order for a question to be eligible for deletion, it must first exist, and then be closed.  In order for a question to be eligible for reopening, it must first exist, then be closed, and then (in most cases) edited in order to bring it up to snuff.  Moreover, I get the impression that most closed questions are never improved...

Comment: ...In short, questions which are eligible for reopening are a subset of questions which have been closed, which are a subset of all questions which have posted.  It should not be surprising that such questions represent a smaller part of the discussion on CRUDE.  Something similar can be said about undeletions, with the additional constraint that one needs 10k XP in order to see such questions, let alone vote to undelete.

Comment: @JyrkiLahtonen You wrote "from what I have seen, the active users of C.R.U.D.E. are also among the most active reopen/undelete voters". I *highly* doubt that. I closely monitor CRUDE and it is quite rare that anything is reopened or undeleted there (except in rare cases when non-crude-members make strong objections, and even then it takes tremendous effort to have a small chance of success).

Comment: @Bill Just to make sure: I am talking about the ratio
$$\frac{\text{undeletions involving a vote from a CRUDE activist}}{\text{all undeletions}}.$$ Possibly also the same ratio with *undeletion* replaced with *reopening*. My point was that Martin Argerami, and possibly also you, was pressing the point that another ratio:
$$\frac{\text{closures involving a vote from a CRUDE activist}}{\text{reopenings involving a vote from a CRUDE activist}}$$ is a larger number. Xander explained that already. Basically it is because most closed posts should be closed, so naturally the latter ratio is hgh.

Comment: In other words, users with an interest in curating site content spend a lot of time on all facets of the curation process. The same applied to the no longer active man with many names. He spent ten times as much time per review task as any of the anti-closure activist. I saw the stats when I was a moderator.

Comment: @Jyrki  I find those claims to be nothing but pure speculation, and 
 they greatly disagree with my experience (esp. for "the man with many names", whose actions I tracked closely).

Comment: @Jyrki I don't know where you got those figures from, but they are complete nonsense as far as they concern me, so I wouldn't be surprised if that was true elsewhere too. You are attempting to draw general inferences from meaningless numbers - not a wise endeavor.

Comment: The numbers for me are surely highly skewed because of the very specific  way that I use the queues. Most of the time when I enter the queues I am not reviewing everything there but, instead, quickly skipping through most to find a *single* post that I want  to vote on (which I already have read, so I can vote on immediately).. Such *highly focused* reviewing accounts for almost all of my "review" activity.  Likely the SE stats don't account well for that atypical behavior. Ditto for "many names" highly atypical behavior.

Comment: @BillDubuque "quickly skipping through most to find a single post that I want to vote on" actually that's an abuse of the queue.

Comment: @quid Thanks for sharing your opinion, but I strongly disagree. I prefer to only review posts on topic where I have much expertise. I recommend that everyone do so.

Comment: @BillDubuque that's fine, please, nevertheless follow the instruction not to use the queues in this form or face the consequences.

Comment: @quid I have no idea what you are talking about.

Comment: @BillDubuque users that do not use the queues as intended get their reviewing privilege revoked.

Comment: @quid Again, thanks for sharing your *personal opinions*.

Comment: @BillDubuque "Do not cherry-pick via skip. If you review, please, try to review the posts that are presented to you. Of course sometimes one feels badly placed or unable to evaluate a post. Then one should skip. But skipping through the queue to find specific types of posts is not really in line with the ideas of the queues." Is written on our meta as guideline for reviewing. We moderators agreed on those guidelines and revoke according to those guidelines. It's not my personal opinion it's how we operate.  If it is our opinion that you should not review anymore, you can't anymore.

Comment: @quid  & Jyrki Please don't ping me any more with such nonsense. The amount of false presumptions made above  is *utterly astounding*. How to lie with statistics *on steroids*!  Those numbers are completely meaningless without any understanding whatsoever of the *context*.

Comment: @JyrkiLahtonen I am not sure it's ideal to have the numbers above posted here. I think I prefer to remove them (together with the rest of the conversation from that point on).

Comment: I did not use any statistics whatsoever. I pointed out that your own description @Bill of your reviewing is directly counter the guidelines. As for the other stats, as said above (before having seen your addition to the comment) I intend to remove them.

Comment: @quid Do you seriously think that the SE designers want users to vote on posts (far outside) their expertise (or interests)?  If so, then the platform is even more poorly designed than I ever imagined. In any case,  I rarely use the queues so it is a moot point.

Comment: @BillDubuque While counting sheep it occurred to me that if a user reviews 9 posts rapidly, and then spends 10 minutes editing the tenth, the average comes to one minute per review. The stats I referred to did not show the distribution of review times, only the average.

Comment: @quid: Sorry, I got carried away. Again. Removing selected comments.

Comment: And, I don't know for sure, but I don't think "skipped" reviews count towards the average, but I may be wrong about that. Also, I did not pay any attention to the average, when it was not based on at least a few dozen reviews.

Comment: The impression that skipped items are not included in the average is bolstered by the fact that the stats included the number of votes of each type the reviewer cast. And, the total number of reviews (for that queue) always was equal to the sum of the numbers of close/leave open votes.

Comment: @Bill But those numbers (deleted as per quid's request) were not "speculation". Their meaning is open to interpretation, but they were there.  I make mistakes, but I own them. But I do not lie. However, it may be better to drop this because A) it is misplaced here, B) only people with diamond powers can verify that data (and with that account now deleted even they may have a hard time retrieving them). It's just that *I have seen those numbers, and as I'm cursed with a good recollection, I will not forget them.*

Comment: @Jyrki Once again you are *way* off the mark in your wild speculations on the motivations of your political opponents. As you surely know from my many remarks on such, I value answers far more than questions, so the review queues are not much use to me since I need to see the answers too in order to properly evaluate the *entire* thread. On the rare occasions that I peruse the review queues it is usually for other purposes, e.g. seeking statistical data such as interactions with CRUDE, or who was robo-voting very poor choices of dupe targets, etc.

Comment: @Jyrki During such perusals I may notice some threads that I know well and (quickly) vote on them but that is very rare (e.g. 12 total reviews in the past 4 months). If you and your crystal ball truly believe that you can infer something meaningful about my motivations from that infinitesimal part of my time spent here then I recommend that you switch careers from math to astrology.

Comment: @Jyrki I thought that I had seen it all a couple months ago when you rudely insisted that I and some other prolific teachers must be motivated by egotistical concerns. But the above is a new low - grossly violating your mod contract by publicizing your (fuzzy memory?) of private data (as above - meaningless without *context*) in order to attack those whose views differ from yours. Will your divisive tactics never end? If there is any hope for the site to flourish once again, then it will be achieved through compromises obtained by striving to understand others - not by viciously attacking them

Comment: @Bill  Exactly where did I speculate about the motives of other users this time?

Comment: Publishing those numbers was a mistake, and quid asked me to remove them, so I did. But my memory is not fuzzy, and I resent any such hints. This started with a bona fide attempt (with those two ratios) to clear up the potential misunderstanding that we (including Martin Argerami) were talking at cross purposes. I'm sorry about my role in the exchange veering off into those review stats.

Answer (score 10):

Promoting some of the comments to an answer so that users can vote on them more freely. I got the impression that at least the OP wanted this to happen. As this is somewhat independent from my longer answer, I want to give the voters the chance to agree/disagree with some parts of what I wanted to say while being indifferent to, or even feeling the opposite way about the other post.

---

I agree with quid's point in that the merit of deletions is to send a loud and clear message that this content is not welcome. I want to emphasize and clarify that, at least for me, the recipients of that message are the **answerers**:

- Answering a duplicate question does not add new content to the site, but it does add more entropy. This is a net loss, and I want to discourage the practice. I am on record (in meta) for being militantly anti-dupe, so I don't want to repeat it all.
- Answering a copy/pasted homework problem invites more of the same, and gives the site a bad reputation as a homework mill. Also, the same assignment was used in the same course a year earlier, so it is often also a duplicate. I want to discourage both asking and answering this type of questions.

> Simply closing the questions does not discourage any of the above practices. All the closed posts can still be voted on. The same applies to duplicates. **Deletion is the only sufficient deterrent at my disposal. And also hitting the answerer is exactly my goal.**

---

But, let's not forget that

- Duplicates are sometimes hard to find. I really should do a better job not making this message *personal*. A biblical parable involving a beam and a mote springs to mind also.
- I want to commend our moderators, and confess that once this fight against dupes/low quality content became too personal for me, and they had to send me a private reminder/warning not to do that.
- I do believe that not all the answerers of LQ questions are in it for the sake of internet points. Yet, when the same names recur as answerers to questions in a close/delete queue I have a hard time A) remembering this, B) believing their excuses. We can blame the gamification aspects of the site for many a bad thing. But, SE wants us to play, so it is not unnatural to ask for a level playing field.

Comment: Unfortunately there are too many different points in one answer - I want to upvote some and downvote others, so the post won't be very useful as an opinion poll. Maybe you should break it into separate answers.

Comment: I see @Bill. I was hoping to prevent that from happening, but I got too riled up, and couldn't keep the lid on. (Scratches head)

Comment: There at least $7$ independent opinions posted in the answer and I wouldn't be surprised if all $2^7 = 128$ possible boolean combinations of such *do* occur in the community. Good luck interpreting the votes.

Comment: That is unfortunate :-( Yet, this is a complicated problem, making contact with several other site policies. And, in spite of the pleas, there are no simple answers.

Answer (score 9):

The site norms about this have gradually changed over the years, so it may be helpful to take a bit of "historical" look at the problem. I think it sheds some additional light.
Also, I try to explain how the *scale*, more precisely, the *growth* of the site also plays a role.

StackOverflow is a couple of years older than us, and an order of magnitude bigger. So it may be a good idea to link to a few posts I find relevant. Both the posts I want to encourage you to read were written by Shog9 - one of the community managers working for StackExchange. He has extensive understanding of the dynamics of these sites (it's his job). He is also one of the CMs who regularly interacts with Math.SE moderators, and, when needed, will post here.

You are welcome to think that I am horribly misrepresenting his points. I probably am. You see, he is using metaphors necessarily open to interpretation. See for yourselves. [His older post](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/256084/5001846) and [a more recent one](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/311901/169003). I probably shouldn't try my hand  using an agricultural metaphor, but I will do it anyway :-)
You can have a field day (bad pun intended) breaking my metaphor. It will do just that. Probably faster than I expect it to.

---

In its infancy this site did not have this problem. There was room for everything. Nearly all the content was new. The users were not unlike happy gardeners in a paradise. Some wanted to nurture rare orchids, some wanted to concentrate on farming food. Yet, everything was small scale. If a weed showed up, we had the resources to study it carefully. Painstakingly isolate it from the wheat and the orchids, try and mutate it to something more interesting. Failing that we would uproot it, by hand, so as not to disturb the plants near by. Some did not want to participate in that kind of gardening, but that was tolerated, because dealing with the weeds was not too time consuming.

When the site started growing, problems started appearing. Some would have liked to continue doing what *they had always done*. Others pointed out the benefits of [crop rotation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Crop_rotation), pointing out that monocropping depletes the soil of some nutrients, making it less fertile for seasons to come, and also making it easier for pests to appear. Fights broke out. In the end some kind of a truce was reached. Even though there was some collateral damage, we still had enough resources to protect some of the useful plants that happened to be close to a weed.

But the site kept growing. Needing to feed a lot of people, we, almost without noticing exactly when the change happened, switched to intensive farming. We still want to do crop rotation. But, the scale has gone up. We no longer have the resources to carefully examine each and every plant by hand. Says Wikipedia: [*It takes very few wild oat plants to cause a significant reduction in the yield of a wheat or cultivated oat field, even though the seeds are a type of oat*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Avena_fatua). So when we spot a few wild oat plants, severe collateral damage will be necessary. The farmer happily sacrifices many good stalks to make sure all the wild oats are destroyed. Whatever it takes to save the main crop.

---

So that's why many deletions **in the current stage of the development of the site** are IMHO necessary.

- The questions may be monocropping duplicates, or pests of attempts to outsource homework.
- Both of those must be stopped, for they will invite their "friends" to crash the party. If the price we have to pay is the destruction of a few correct answers, so be it.

---

But, that's not the end of it. What lies in the future? Reread [Shog9's later post](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/311901/169003). Water. If we don't accommodate for it, it will destroy the farm. And. Water. Does. Not. Care. What/who is water here? Many interpretations are possible. His most important message may be (my interpretation) that we all need to brace for a future when we **ALL** need to compromise on some of our dearest principles. Linking to [the infamous post describing four types of SE users](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/252077/5001846)

1. The librarians may be forced to accept that they cannot have full control of the content. Some may leave the site in disgust, but do observe that the librarians will get reinforcements from the ranks of former prolific answerers.
2. The noobs will also need to learn the site norms. But, the continued existence of the site needs new users. Many a noob will inadvertently start out as one of this type. But we need many of them to stay.
3. The most knowledgable of the noobs will become prolific answerers. If left to themselves usually not adding new content. So they will need to learn to compromise. And, in the end, they will be converted to librarians (seen this happen a few times already)...
4. ... or possibly to an apathic shaking their head on the sidelines (this fate awaits a few librarians also).

---

But, while all this played out, there was the hermit, happily tending to a few orchids. Not worrying about the ego points and politics. Just beautiful math. Very Zen (unless somebody steps on his orchids).

Answer (score 3):

*My opinion, lifted from some comments I wrote above. It is not solving the problem, but arguing that the current approach to said problem is misguided.*

I will develop my argumentation by building on two comments left by @postmortes (comments I disagree with), who wrote

> "[I think] that's what the debate is about: whether this really is a site to get your homework done for you"

and

> "If the site isn't about getting your homework done then it will be hard for anyone to argue that PSQs shouldn't be deleted."

Indeed, we are talking about *past*, *already answered* PSQs, **not** new ones. The debate is rather

> *Is deleting those past, answered, closed questions an efficient way to prevent new ones (PSQs, HW, etc) appearing?*

And I don't think the answer is that clear. Namely:

- The OPs of those closed, answered questions were usually first-time posters; were either discouraged by the response (closure) or got what they want, and are probably not coming back anyway: so it won't affect them.
- Newcomers won't see the deleted questions, so won't learn from their closure/erasure.

So it doesn't deter the **posters**.  The only possible argument is then that it will deter the **answerers** from answering those poor-quality undesirable questions *in the future*. Right?

But that's penalizing said answerers for things they answered 5 months or even 5 years ago! I really doubt this will have the desired effect. 
Instead of changing their future behavior, that might just (understandably, if you ask me) piss them off and drive them away — and thus also lead to fewer good answers on good questions.

So you end up with less valuable content (which in many case was good quality, even though the questions were not), and fewer of the previous answerers willing to contribute to good content in the future. Maybe I'm pessimistic, but that does not seem like a sound policy to implement.

Comment: This is probably quite difficult to quantify. Some user might leave because they see some of their content deleted (or content provided by others). Some users might leave because they see that Mathematics Stack Exchange resembles a homework mill. So the same actions which might drive some part of users away might be helpful in keeping other users on the site.

Comment: @MartinSleziak Yes, and I did add these caveats (it's my opinion, and the conclusion in the middle is "I don't think the answer is that clear."). I believe it's therefore important to have these conversations, instead of simply having a few (or even many) people going to implement these new half-baked policies on their own without actually consulting first (which, and maybe I'm wrong, looks like what's currently happening). However, given the (at the time of writing) 3 "close" votes on the OP's question, some people may not agree this conversation is worth having.

Comment: The examples in the question mostly seem to be rather recent questions. Thus the argument on old stuff is somewhat besides the point. There is also a built in mechanism. Namely points for well-received old content are not lost after deletion.

Comment: @quid Good point. I didn't know that mechanism (so indeed, 5 years may not be really a problem. Not sure what that mechanism is, though -- where is it documented?)

Comment: The thing about reputation which quid mentioned can be found here: [Do you lose the reputation (points) you acquired from a question if/when it is deleted?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/13762#150096) and [Reputation tab seems to be insensitive to deletion of upvoted answers](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/24905). (However, I would hope that this site has enough users for who the reputation points are not really that important.)

Comment: Indeed you're right especially with your last paragraph, there was this user André Nicolas whom used to answer PSQ question and then people started to delete them, and that made him wanted to leave MSE and leaving MSE wouldn't affect just lazy students but also good math students.

Comment: I get your point. However, I am not sure that characterizing this as *new* and done *without consulting* is accurate. This topic (or at least very close to this) was discussed on meta several times, for example, here is a post from 2014: [Under what circumstances is it appropriate to delete a question that has received a good answer?](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/16462)

Comment: @Isa well, and then they did not leave but continued to answer, until then they stopped to be active for in all likelihood altogether different reasons.

Comment: Re: *Newcomers won't see the deleted questions.* That's true. Still they see the ones that are not deleted and can use them as examples. There were many posts on meta of the form: "Why was my question closed? Look - this one is similar and it wasn't." (Of course, this is argument more in favor of closure than in favor of deleting. Even if the question is kept, it should be clear that it does not have sufficient quality. Here is a relatively recent related discussion: [Historical lock for preserving old, low quality questions](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/29471).)

Comment: Clement, thanks for coming here. If a representative fraction of users opposed to deletions would come to a round table discussion, then we might actually talk it over and come up with a compromise. Alas, I'm not very optimistic about that happening, but I appreciate your effort.

Comment: @quid yes but he wanted to leave, and if he continued answering then that's because he had a good heart and wanted to give us more of his knowledge.

Comment: BTW several of the older discussion that are already linked suggest *reposting* the question in such cases  - with keeping the requirements on the question in mind. If, in addition, the answers from the deleted questions are [merged](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/tags/merging/info) into the new question, they are not lost. Here is a topic discussing specifically reposting of questions: [Is it okay to re-ask a deleted question?](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/29136)

Comment: because he clearly didn't care about the reputation because when it's deleted then the rep goes too.

Comment: OTOH, I disagree with your conclusion in the sense that **deterring answers to bad questions** is exactly the goal here. If it works as a deterrent, fine, mission accomplished. But it does not look like it works. We have plenty of users making an industry out of answering PSQs.

Comment: @JyrkiLahtonen Regarding your last point -- then, why not having downvoting? And I don't mean *no-notice* downvoting (I personally hate when someone downvotes a seemingly fine answer with no comment), but with a line saying "This answer is correct, but shouldn't have been posted, as it is in reply to a low-quality question/PSQ"

Comment: The content stays, the question gets closed, but the answerer doesn't reap as many points they wanted (or, even, loses some). That's a good deterrent... (also, why does upvoting still allow one to get points on closed questions? Isn't that counterproductive?)

Comment: Yet another option is a mechanism that would convert those answers as a "Community wiki" analogue. No more actual points gained -- again, a valid deterrent against answering low-quality questions for the sake of gaining points.

Comment: @ClementC [Like what I suggested here?](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/a/18871/11619) Not impossible. The objections raised were: A) it does not deter the answerers not motivated by rep points, and B) it does not deter the answerers motivated by rep points, because many upvotes come quickly, and a moderator on-duty cannot convert the thread to CW fast enough unless they learn about it very quickly.

Comment: A downvote? It is not a deterrent to an answerer motivated by rep.  The reason is that the difference a downvote makes is the difference between +50 and +48 rep points. OTOH, a deletion (if done within the 60 day window) is the difference between +50 and +0. You see why only one of the alternative actions is actually a deterrent.

Comment: I see. That's a drag -- there ought to be a way to remove the points while keeping the contents... (what the community answer option does, basically) @JyrkiLahtonen

Comment: A downvote with an explanation? In theory that could work. Educating each other about the issues we have, and all that. The practice is somewhat different. I confess to not having been sufficiently calm when trying this. Therefore the results I got were not good. The volume of bad questions leads to exasperation, which in turn leads to less than constructive ways of phrasing an explanation to a downvote :-/

Comment: @JyrkiLahtonen Oh, for that, no need to come up with a new phrasing. Why not [a template one](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/4925/list-of-comment-templates)?

Comment: Yes, using a template would solve that problem.

Comment: @Isa and others want to leave because of the volume of content they do not appreciate, including answers to poor questions. Yet they stay because they have a good heart and despite all the frustration keep trying to maintain the quality of the resources. There is no monopoly for goodheartedness with those that answer a lot.

Comment: Considering the close votes to this question, most of which are from the very users who are taking the close-deletion action mentioned in the post, I now have more doubt on the justification of coordinated deletion in the CRUDE room. They do not even bother to post an answer stating clearly the merits they think exist.

Comment: @Jack Not to be presumptuous, but maybe they agree with my answer, no need for duplicating answers. Voting suffices. Further, while you insist that this is not a dupe, arguably the same discussion was had numerous times already. Right, if you want you can have your new thread, but you cannot expect that everybody engages in a near identical discussion yet again.

Comment: @ClementC. I only skimmed them for now. I don't think such escalating rhetoric is useful. If you think something is over  the line please flag it.

Comment: @quid Thanks for taking the time to answer!

Comment: @Jack I considered posting an answer here.  However, my answer would have been nearly identical to quid's.  Thus I upvoted his answer.  That being said, I am not one of the people who voted to close this question, so perhaps you were not addressing me as part of the "...very users who are taking the close-deletion action mentioned in the post."

Comment: @XanderHenderson: thanks for your comment. "so perhaps you were not addressing me as part of the ..." Well, that's why I used "most of which", not "all".

Comment: @Jack "They do not even bother to post an answer stating clearly the merits they think exist." What quid said. Also, it looks like the people not searching for duplicates in main, don't search for them in meta either. Did you search at all? Or just responded to the comments pointing out several closely related threads?