# Does the moderator violate the EoQS?

Tags: discussion, moderators, policy

This recent question on the main site: [If whenever $|x-a|<\delta$, $|y-a|<\delta$ then $|f(x)-f(y)|<\epsilon$, is this equiv. to $f$ cont. at $c$ then $f$ cont. on some interval around $c$?](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/4488341)

has nothing but a question statement. The moderator who wrote the [EoQS](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/33508) posted an [answer](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/4489456) to it.

**Question**: Does the moderator violate the EoQS?

---

[Added.]

Users are pointing to the exact meaning of the acronym "EoQS" and "EoQS" should really be "QS" in the original question. Since EoQS is specifically used, the question could be written as

> Does the moderator violate the QS in the EoQS?

Since there have been comments/answers under the posts, I would keep the question as what it is, in case of confusion.

Some comments confuse "mentioning someone" with "name-calling" and accuse this post unfoundedly of a "personal attack". **No**. This post simply states facts and asks a question:

- the asker is not at all judging the quality of the linked question; "has nothing but a question statement" is a fact that anyone can see by the link.
- the asker tags this post with `discussion`, `moderators`, and `policy`, which is what this post is about: asking if the moderator violates the quality standards in the EoQS they write.

---

I find it very confusing regarding site policies that the mod writing the following comment:

> In any event, at the time that I answered the question, it
> (1) had been on the site for two days,
> (2) didn't seem to have any obvious duplicates on the site,
> (3) had an upvote (so it seemed to have been positively received), and
> (4) had a positively scored answer (which I felt was not the most relevant or interesting example, but that is a matter of taste).

while closing another (now undeleted) [question](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/4498906), which, as a user [points out](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/35060/does-the-moderator-violate-the-eoqs#comment164916_35060),

> (1) had been on the site for several weeks;
> (2) doesn't seem to have obvious duplicates;
> (3) had 8 upvotes (so it seems to have been positively received);
> (4) had a (very!) positively scored answer. I find it hard to swallow the idea that this question is obviously of low-quality, and should not have been answered.

Comment: Generally the community here doesn't like individuals being named and shamed in public, and this seems like a direct personal attack.  Also, you should explain what context you think that question could have -- it seems reasonable to me.

Comment: @postmortes: this is not any ordinary individual; this question is tagged with [`moderator`](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/moderators). Particularly, the mentioned moderator is the very mod who drafted the EoQS, which influences all the users of the site. I do not see any attack at all. If you think the answer should be a clear no, then say it in an answer instead of attacking my post.

Comment: @pos: "you should explain what context you think that question could have" No. I am not voting to close the question, nor do I upvote or downvote for it. I simply state that the post only has a one-sentence statement, which is a "problem statement question", mentioned in the post of EoQS.

Comment: I don't consider this succinct post a PSQ, due to its implied context [and author](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4504063/spivak-interpretation-of-motivation-behind-definition-ex-expx#comment9454111_4504063). But with the EoQS being [how it is](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/a/35035/21813), who knows what reviewers will think? $\quad$ P.S. @user1046533 It's not *literally* a PSQ: the author is offering their translation and inquiring if they have understood correctly.

Comment: In my mind the context here is the Theorem, and the problem statement is asking if the Theorem can be strengthened in a certain fashion.   Tempting as it might be to suspect that, the answer is negative, which can be established by counterexamples (more or less the content of the two Answers posted so far).

Comment: @postmortes Not true. Speaking as a former mod, I can assure you that there is a long history of critiques of named diamond mods on meta, and the mod's usernames have been allowed to remain in the posts - even after removal requests, and even when the critiques were unfounded or based on misunderstandings, even by the current mod team. Unfortunately this leaves the door open for political based attacks on particular mods - which *have* occurred, and likely will continue to do so given said precedents.

Comment: @SouravGhosh The standards on Math SE do not require an asker to provide "an attempt", and I have long argued that "attempts" provide the lowest form of context.  In the case of this question, definitions are provided, the question is somewhat natural (I've had many students ask questions similar to this one), and there is no clear duplicate question on the site.  What further context do you believe would improve the question?  Do you honestly believe that a half-baked attempt would make the question *better*?

Comment: @user1046533 EoQS is a *procedure* for working with users who post a lot of answers to low quality questions.  It is an enforcement protocol for users who violate policies regarding quality.  It is impossible for one to "violate" EoQS, as it is not a policy.  Presumably, you mean to accuse me of violating quality standards.  You have provided little evidence of this---until today, that question had a positive reception, and no close votes. Also, as you mentioned EoQS, you presumably have a list of low-quality questions which I have answered?  And not just this one (perhaps marginal) question?

Comment: @XanderHenderson Literally no definitions are provided. But if you say that being a natural and answerable with the information provided in the question is enough to not fall under the "lacking context" closure reason, I'd actually be happy. It just seems like a sharp departure from how this rule has been enforced so far.

Comment: @MaoWao I apologize---I mean that the relevant proposition is stated.  They have stated a theorem which follows from the definition of continuity.  Presumably, they know that the proposition is true (I proved it in my answer for completeness, but it is not necessary).  In the context of the question, I took this proposition to be a "definition", and the stated result regarding continuity as a possibly equivalent statement.  In any event, I am not holding up this question as *amazing*, or as a stellar example, but I believe that it meets the minimum requirements...

Comment: e.g. it is not simply a homework question, or "solve my problem for me" question.

Comment: @XanderHenderson Without any further evidence you can't conclude that this is not a homework question. Probably it is not a stronger assumption.

Comment: @SouravGhosh It is not a routine homework exercise in the sense that it is not a problem that is meant to be solved algebraically, or via some technique in differential equations, or whatnot.  It is not an exercise which has infinite variation through changing a few numbers.  It might be an exercise in some analysis text somewhere, but it is not a routine, rote, computation, i.e. not "simply a homework question".

Comment: @XanderHenderson To me this illustrates the problems with the "no context" closing reason very well: It was a foul compromise from the beginning between people who wanted to ban homework questions and people who didn't. The context requirement works ok-ish for lower level questions although it sometimes can feel like the OP has to jump the hoop (there's certainly context that could have been provided in this specific example - not that I think it would have improved the question ...). But for questions in advanced topics I think this requirement does not work at all in the direction of (1/2)

Comment: In any event, at the time that I answered the question, it (1) had been on the site for two days, (2) didn't seem to have any obvious duplicates on the site, (3) had an upvote (so it seemed to have been positively received), and (4) had a positively scored answer (which I felt was not the most relevant or interesting example, but that is a matter of taste).  I find it hard to swallow the idea that this question is obviously of low-quality, and should not have been answered.  It is, I think, borderline at worst.  To be attacked for answering such a question is galling.

Comment: ... preventing unwanted lazy homework questions. It does drive away good people with interesting questions though. (2/2)

Comment: @MaoWao "It was a foul compromise from the beginning between people who wanted to ban homework questions and people who didn't." You'll get no argument from me on this.  But I am in the "ban homework questions" camp.

Comment: @XanderHenderson Can you refer me some links where I can find  not "simply a homework question" meets Quality standards? Because I so confused about this policy.

Comment: @SouravGhosh I have already outlined my position, and I am not sure what you find unclear about it. I don't hold this question up as an exemplar of a good question, but, in my opinion, it passes a fairly minimal bar:  it is a natural question, the relevant proposition/definition is stated, it does not *appear* (to me) to be a routine exercise, and I don't know what additional context could be provided which would improve the question (I have asked you to suggest additional context---the response you seemed to give is "an attempt"; in my opinion, this would not improve the question).

Comment: @MaoWao: "Literally no definitions are provided". Check also this recent [one](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/4498906) that is closed.

Comment: @ryang: "I don't consider this succinct post a PSQ" - well, see this [recent one](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/4498906/1046533).

Comment: @user1046533 Per the [timeline](https://math.stackexchange.com/posts/4498906/timeline), I cast the *fifth* close vote on that question.

Comment: @XanderHenderson: [this question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4498906/why-is-there-no-analogue-to-the-classification-of-finitely-generated-abelian-g) (1) had been on the site for several weeks; (2) doesn't seem to have obvious duplicates; (3) had 6 upvotes (so it seems to have been positively received);  (4) had a (very!) positively scored answer. I find it hard to swallow the idea that this question is obviously of low-quality, and should not have been answered. Yet, you voted "not suitable for this site".

Comment: @MartinArgerami Again, at the time that I voted to close it, I cast the *fifth* close vote.  I also have not called out anyone for violating site policy by answering it, or attempted to smear the answerer.  There is a spectrum between "this is a question which no one should have answered, thus the answerers should be notified of site policy" and "this is a question which, in the opinion of five members of the community, does not meet the quality standards of the site, but other users might disagree."

Comment: @XanderHenderson: I don't know whether you can see something on the timeline that non-moderators can't, but from what I can see, you were the only close voter on that question.

Comment: @EricWofsey Then perhaps I can see something that others cannot.  In the timeline, I see four other close votes (prior to my own).  In any event, I am not really sure why that question is relevant, as I have not suggested that the answerer of the question be pilloried for having answer it.

Comment: For what it's worth, the question on classification of abelian groups has now been undeleted.

Comment: Concerning a recent answer here : this post does not come across as explicitly confrontational to me, but going by the votes on that answer a fair few have detected underlying tones. Please assume good intentions, everybody :  this definitely includes the OP and the answerer below. There is more middle ground than the extremes imagine, let us try to explore it rather than rant. As far as I'm concerned, this question is borderline because it contains at least *one* "unit" of context, and I wouldn't apply an EoQS flag to such a question. It still depends, though.

Comment: @MartinArgerami Surely that question should have been closed. It is low quality and a duplicate of one or several earlier versions. Qiaochu's answer can be salvaged by relocating it. The timeline shows that there were votes to close it, but those were invalidated. I guess they age after a week. Anyway, I fail to see how that question is relevant to the discussion in this thread.

Comment: @JyrkiLahtonen: none of those who voted to close and to delete that question did anything to save Qiaochu's answer, so I fail to see your point. And I cannot possibly imagine in what sense this site is better without that question than with it. Over the last few years thousands of questions, some with amazing answers, have been deleted because the asker "didn't provide context"; it's ridiculous. And as for how the question is relevant, it fulfills the exact same list of reasons that a moderator found good enough to post himself an answer to a PSQ.

Comment: @MartinArgerami Qiaochu is quite capable of saving his answer by posting it in one of the duplicate targets. Anyway, it is not the responsibility of voters to save the good answers. You are misplacing the burden. If you want to change the rules re context and EoQS you can run for a diamond moderator position, and rally for support from the voters.

Comment: @Jyrki "it is not the responsibility of voters to save the good answers". One can of course cast deletion every day in the way they like, don't they? But *does* such collaborated deletion of posts all together with good answers *make the site any better at all*, **that** is a big question. If such deletion itself is not at all useful and even harmful, then yes, I do think the "burden" should be on them.

Comment: @user1046533 Correct, that is a big question with a long history. Lest you post a duplicate, please check out at least [1](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/16462/11619) and [2](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/29972/11619), and the earlier threads linked to those. I don't think either of us would enjoy it, if I attempt to rehash all that here. You see that a compromise of sorts was reached back in the day (partly due to exhaustion). Anyway, a compromise (like the QS in EoQS) is better than one side having it all their way, don't you think.

Comment: @JyrkiLahtonen: was Qiaochu notified that his answer was deleted? How could he possibly save it? The times I have found that one of my answers was deleted, was by pure chance.

Comment: @MartinArgerami That's another facet that has been covered in the earlier threads. There are several ways of finding out about deleted answers in a matter of seconds. You are not going to rope me into discussing yet another tangent.

Comment: @JyrkiLahtonen: if you think that that a user should be actively searching for deleted answers without being notified then yes, we have little to discuss.

Comment: @MartinArgerami It's more like A) I doubt neither of us would say anything that has not been said in the past threads. Some of them already linked to here. B) It is unrelated to the topic of this thread. If you want to rip off old band-aids, go ahead, nothing will stop you. I will not go through that pain again. C) As a former moderator Qiaochu is particularly well aware of the possibilities the site software offers.

Comment: @MartinArgerami May be you did not notice that Qiaochu's answer was on a *recent* question, when its deletion results in a dip in his rep score, and is therefore nearly impossible not to notice.

Comment: @JyrkiLahtonen: "nearly impossible?" Because of this thread I went to check on my deleted answers and I found many of my upvoted answers deleted that I knew nothing about . Many (some?) of us are not checking reputaton that closely, and I don't think that we should. Saying that it is the user's responsibility to find which of their contributations were deleted without their knowledge nor consent, sounds asinine to me.

Comment: @MartinArgerami In an ideal world the site software might give such notifications. Feel free to post such a feature request in MetaStackExchange. I'm sure the request would garner some support. But it seems to me that you are really blaming the janitors for doing their thankless work. And, as witnessed here, the site is self-correcting in such matters. It is a core principle of this network of sites that no matter who you are, everything you post is subject to the reviews of others. No one has the right to post thousands of "do not erase" notices on the chalkboards here.

Answer (score 9):

We can, of course, discuss the merits of answering that particular question. Or lack thereof. I just want to remind you all of the fact that EoQS is statistical in nature. All the EoQS sanctions I have seen, have hit users who have *a habit of answering low quality questions*. Of course, that is a vague description. I guess that *habit* is a weighted linear combination of:

- a high fraction of all the answers posted by a user are on low quality questions, and
- the total number of answers posted by a user on low quality questions.

Further factors are undoubtedly:

- the time span (answering $>x$ low quality questions in a week or some such period may be actionable under EoQS, but taking a year to do the same need not be),
- the role of duplicates (Bill Dubuque and yours truly would give them a lot of weight, even though we have differences of opinion on the details), but the only comment I have gotten from the diamond moderators is that duplicates are a lower priority (in comparison to, say PSQs).

We are not given detailed threshold numbers. Nor should we, because disclosing that data **will** lead to some users skirting the rule.

In light of this, I think (may be only me, posting this to collect opinions, comments and more information)

> A single post is never actionable under EoQS.

A handful of posts may lead to a friendly mod message reminding a poster about the rule, but sanctions take more. As in disregarding the rule.

I think @rschwieb basically nailed it in their answer.

---

Another nitpick (answering the title of the question). EoQS stands for *enforcement* of the quality standards. Moderators do the enforcing, so the only way a moderator can violate the EoQS is by not enforcing it.

Yes, I know that some posters interpreted the question to be asking whether the moderator in question violated the Quality Standards. I couldn't resist, sorry :-)

Comment: A single post isn't a violation, sure, but the question is what type of single posts collect into a violation of EOQS?

Comment: A handful of posts may also lead to an unfriendly mod message.

Comment: You're right that it is statistical in nature. Perhaps it's only me, but I thought the question was more along the lines of "Should an answer like this be flagged for moderator intervention under EoQS?" which pertains to this specific question. Two other answers seem to take the same route. In any case, you're right.

Comment: @SarveshRavichandranIyer That is a possible interpretation. Yet, the tone of the post also sounds like an attack on a single moderator (that's fine, comes with the job, been there at the receiving end) or an attempt to rally for support to overturn EoQS. The **title** is closer to that, don't you think :-)

Comment: Wasn't the whole EOQS mega thread an attempt to rally people into understanding and enforcing EOQS? I mean I don't think it's really an issue to rally for support on meta.

Comment: @JyrkiLahtonen I will concede the last point, for sure.

Comment: Fair enough @Beautifullyirrational. The poster could have achieved that without singling out a scapegoat. I concede that I would have tried to make my posts more objective, if I had not also wanted to give a voice support to the individual. You also see that in the comments other unrelated points are being rallied for. The thread became one of general complaints. I guess that isn't very unusual either.

Comment: "Yet, the tone of the post also sounds like an attack on a single moderator (that's fine, comes with the job, been there at the receiving end)". I agree with the first part, disagree with the second. People who are rude to mods tend to be rude to other users as well. When I teach I have a policy of mutual respect for all members of the class, and the teacher is a member of the class too.

Comment: I can understand why it would look bad (heck, be bad) for mods to delete items criticizing themselves, but for Mod A to enforce standards of respect towards Mod B would, I think, be an all-around good for the community.

Comment: I see the point @JonathanZsupportsMonicaC. But I also feel that leaving threads like this around is a display of strength from the entire moderator. Something of the scale of EoQS is never a whim of a single moderator (even though, necessarily, a single moderator had to write that post). Leaving it around shows the futility of attacking an individual diamond bearer. Of course, in the interest of fairness, it is also important to allow dissenting voices to be aired. More constructive criticism would include suggestions of other solutions to the problems EoQS seeks to address.

Comment: (cont'd) Which could then lead to a better solution.

Comment: I think this answer addresses the issues well. The community as a whole has come to a particular view of things. I am a bit of a dissenter on the grounds that I would prioritise more helping new users to learn and enjoy mathematics. However, certain kinds of bad behaviour became endemic and changes were necessary. But if we are to be a community then we have to do better than thinking the worst of everyone else and reacting with suspicion to everything people do. It takes more time, for example, to learn how to ask a good question on the site than it used to.

Comment: @JyrkiLahtonen - I see your point about demonstrating moderator strength, but I'll let you know that while dissenting voices definitely need to be allowed, when they come as  personal attacks they create a hostile air that affects the entire community.

Comment: ... Every system which answers questions is potentially exploitable. There is a point beyond which dealing with potential exploitation gets in the way of the main purposes of the site (over-regulation). Mathematicians are often perfectionists. We can't have a perfect system.

Answer (score 7):

Ok, so I'll try speak a bit candidly. While the EOQS could be phrased in whatever way, I feel the underlying idea behind it was to cut down on calculation heavy/ textbook example type/routine problems which appear on the site.

The question mentioned here looks to me like one which involves helping OP out with their speculation rather than some routine question which comes in the textbook which makes engaging with it okay.

Comment: Great short answer. Personally, I think the sentiment across most of the comments is the same : in a "strictly guidelines" sense, it contains nothing apart from another minor result as context, which I would not consider sufficient if I were to take a hard stance. However, a closer look at the question reveals its novelty and a need to preserve it with the help of a good answer. That is being reflected (eventually!) in the votes here.

Answer (score 5):

This is a protest answer.  Other answers and comments have made a great show of answering the question that could have been fairly asked:

> Shouldn't question X have been treated as not meeting quality standards? I don't think it meets them, but then again a person who knows a lot about the quality standards deigned to answer it.  Am I missing something obvious?

That would indicate the asker would be demonstrating a sincere effort to reconcile their understanding of EoQS with the question posted.

Is that what the post here is?  I have no doubt it is not.  What we have here is a ham-fisted attempt to undermine EoQS by insinuating the "author of the EoQS*" has acted hypocritically by answering it.  Secondarily it has the other common stratagem to undermine EoQS which is to apply it in a superficial way which ignores discretion, banking on the casual observer thinking the results look bad, in an attempt to sour opinion and cast doubt on the whole endeavor.

I think that as we see posts like this occur, we should be more critical about whether they are

1. Unduly personal (sometimes I suppose they are necessarily personal, but not in a case like this one.)
2. Roundabout, in the sense that they are not directly portraying the concern they voice, but playing games like the ones described above in an attempt to sway casual readers' opinion.

If it is either of these things we should insist on rewriting to mitigate both, because if we don't, it just enables more such posts from the underbelly of rhetoric.  For years we've often quietly ignored these bad behaviors while giving the answer to what should have been asked, but maybe we should be less accommodating.

<sup>* If this over-assignment of responsibility isn't evidence of the unduly personal nature of this post, I don't know what is.</sup>

<sup>** Normally opponents of the EoQS take exception that too many questions are closed in its name, but here a post is thrown under the bus just to forward an agenda of undermining the EoQS.  Such an opponent should rather view the continued existence of the linked question a good thing (that the EoQS isn't indiscriminately used), rather than a chance to play games.</sup>

Comment: **-1**. Your answer is mostly attacking the asker and unfoundedly assuming a bad position. I am not questioning/criticizing but stating that the mentioned post on the main site has only one sentence, which is not consistent with the EoSQ standard. //"Normally opponents of the EoQS" PLEASE do not split the site in such a way. There are no opponents but users of the MSE here.// This answer nowhere attempts to answer the question in the post.

Comment: We expect questions on the front page to be edited to meet site standards. Is there a similar policy on Meta?

Comment: Hmm, that didn't seem to address my question.

Comment: If a person felt swayed to a certain political view for MSE by simply reading this post, that means they themself felt some sort of issue was there from before itself. I believe, this post was really a nice opportunity for the community to grow closer and to check if what we are doing is what we are saying.

Comment: This post was an ugly attack on a single member of our community.

Comment: You titled it "Does the moderator violate the EoQS?". That's the topic.

Answer (score 2):

Reason $1$ : In the mentioned question op doesn't provide any attempt. More generally we don't know how much op can understand. OP just give two statements and asked to prove equivalence between them.

How much evidence we have to support that this is not a homework question?

---

---

Reason $2$ :
This
question ( [If whenever $|x-a|<\delta$, $|y-a|<\delta$ then $|f(x)-f(y)|<\epsilon$, is this equiv. to $f$ cont. at $c$ then $f$ cont. on some interval around $c$?](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/4488341/977780) ) can be decomposed with two parts:

Part $1(\text{statement} P$):

> If $f$ is continuous at $a$, then for any $\epsilon>0$ there is a
> $\delta>0$ so that whenever $|x-a|<\delta$ and $|y-a|<\delta$, we have
> $|f(x)-f(y)|<\epsilon$.

Part $2 (\text{statement}$Q$)$

> if $f$ is continuous at a point $c$ then it is continuous on some interval around that point $c$?

Both the parts have solid duplicate target.

Duplicate for part $1$ :

[Prove that if f is continuous in a, then $\forall \epsilon > 0, ∃ \delta >0: $ $|x-a|< \delta $ & $|y-a| < \delta $ $ then |f(x)-f(y)| < \epsilon $](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/2750887/977780)

Duplicate for part $2$:

[Proof of continuity of Thomae Function at irrationals.](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/530097/977780)

[Proof of the continuity of a function at irrational points](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/1367726/977780)

[$f(x) = x$ when x is rational, $f(x) = 0$ when x is irrational. Find all points at which $f$ is continous.](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/2526233/977780)

The great one

[Constructing Continuous functions at given points](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/7821/977780)

---

The main question is about the equivalence between $P$ and $Q$. And this is clear form two duplicate posts.

---

If a moderator has the power to close a question with multiple duplicate, then it would be better to close the question  as duplicate. Even one it could be closed with a single duplicate and probably one example in the comment.

---

If I am not wrong it's a low quality question.

Note : I don't want to abuse any moderator. This post directed to all users including myself. It's our responsibility to improve the site's health.

---

**UPDATE**:

One counter example is enough! Op needs only one counter example to think about the problem.

Justification : See the [accepted answer](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/4488350/977780).

---

$\textbf{I apologize for my ignorant post}$

Comment: The question asked in the lede here is not about the truth of the two statements, independent of each other, but is about the *equivalence* of the two statements.  While the questions you have highlighted contain some of the details, no answer to any of those questions is a complete answer to the question asked here.

Comment: Note:  moderators and gold badge holders in an appropriate tag can close a question as a duplicate of many targets.  However, the point of this is to direct a user to several posts, any one of which should provide an answer.  It is *not* meant to provide users with a list of questions which, when stitched together, will answer the question.  Otherwise, why not post a handful of "questions" that list the axioms of analysis (or number theory, or whatever), then close every question in that tag as part of a duplicate chain which leads to the axioms?

Comment: I have already mentioned in my post that I don't know the site's policy very well. I have came up this answer with a little knowledge. In the mentioned question op doesn't provide any attempt. More generally we don't how how much op can understand. OP just give  two statements and asked to prove  equivalence between them. I don't want to argue with you as you have more experience than me and you know the site very well. Take it as a weak suggestion and ignore all the things.

Comment: I think this post should stay as it shows a positive example of how through calmly discussing that a mutual understanding between parties of opposing opinions can be achieved